# Upload PrimeFaces Diretório

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou fazendo um upload com PrimeFaces onde o upload esta na pasta Resources do Projeto, porém desejo utilizar outro diretório para armazenamento dos arquivos, preferencialmente no diretório raiz onde esta o Tomcat.

Alguma sugestão de como obter este caminho?

Atualmente estou utilizando assim: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/") + "resources/files/";`

Comment: E onde está o TomCat? qual o endereço dele..

Answer (score 1):

Edite o arquivo `web.xml` e inclua ou altere a entrada:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
    <param-value>/path/to/uploads</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666370/where-does-pfileupload-save-my-file

Comment: Informei um caminho tipo /User/MeuUser/Imagens porem quando retorna para o view ele concatena localhost:8080/Projeto/User/MeuUser/Imagens/minhaimg.jpg Logo a Imagem não é exibida pois o caminha não existe dentro do server.

Answer (score 0):

Estou usando desta forma:
XHTML: `<p:graphicImage value="#{emitenteBean.myImage}"`

BEAN:

```
private StreamedContent myImage;

try {
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/Users/user/files/minhaImg.jpg");
myImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(fileInputStream, "image/jpeg");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("ERRO AO CONVERTER IMG.");
    }
```